# styles are not correctly applied in Microsoft Edge. IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, rendering, microsoft-edge

Page is rendered correctly in all browsers except Microsoft Edge/IE. I have a grunt task for adding autoprefixers, which is expected to solve this kind of problems:

```
autoprefixer: {
  options: {
      browsers: ['last 2 versions']
  },
  main: {
    expand: true,
    flatten: true,
    src: ['css/fromless/*.css'],
    dest: 'css/autoprefixed/'
  }
},
```

Here how it looks in Microsoft Edge/IE:

[image]

Here how it should look:

[image]

What potentially could be a problem?

Here is the layout online http://amirm.idhost.kz/aviata/

Comment: We will need to see more code, or have access to an online example, to better assist.

Comment: @Sampson, here is the layout online http://amirm.idhost.kz/aviata/

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without the code or a sample, however it's important to understand that autoprefixer is intended to take unprefixed css file and add vendor prefixes if required.

One mistake I have seen before is a developer sends in prefixed code and expects it to come out with the alternative vendor prefixes from other browser vendors.

Take a look at your code, if you have thing's like -webkit-border-radius (or anything containing, -ms -webkit -moz) then remove all of those prefixes.

Auto prefixer will then add those prefixes back in to your css only if they are still necessary (if required by the last 2 versions of the browser)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I will check it and write about outcome